# Should a boolean field or a separate table be used?

Tags: mysql, database

In order to learn MySQL I'm building a music CD database, which is pretty complex but so far I'm doing rather well. I have set up, among others, a table with `albums`, another with `artists` and an `album_artists` one which links `album_id`'s with `artist_id`'s. But in an album with various artists, usually one, or some, of them are the main artists, so when making a query I shouldn't order them by alphabetical or id order, but by primary or secondary. Question is:
Should I make a separate table of `secondary_artists`, identical to the original `album_artists` one, or make a boolean `isPrimary` field in the `album_artists` table? Are both ways acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many bibliographic / discographic schemes for recording multiple creators assign an ordinal number to each contributor. So, instead of a flag indicating "primary", your album_artist table could contain

```
      album_id artist_id artist_order
```

So if

- "Daylight Again" had album_id 314,
- David Crosby had artist_id 87,
- Steven Stills had artist id 33,
- Graham Nash had artist id 50,

your album_artist table would have these rows.

```
album_id  artist_id artist_order
  312        87         1
  312        33         2
  312        50         3
```

This would give you sufficient information to get the artists in the order mentioned in the work (which is the right order for most catalogs).

Don't put "secondary" artists in a different table.